# Understanding Python Lists and Dictionaries using the example

Tags: python

Using this following example:

For each human in the world I would like to create my own list which I can iterate over..

```
persons = []
attributes = {}

for human in world:
     attributes['name'] = human['name']
     attributes['eye_color'] = human['eyes']
     persons.append(attributes)
```

Now when I try to print out each name in my own list:

```
for item in persons:
    print item['name']
```

They are all the same, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *reusing the same dictionary* over and over again. `persons.append(attributes)` adds a reference to that dictionary to the list, it does *not* create a copy.

Create a new dictionary *in* your loop:

```
persons = []

for human in world:
     attributes = {}
     attributes['name'] = human['name']
     attributes['eye_color'] = human['eyes']
     persons.append(attributes)
```

Alternatively, use [`dict.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) to create a shallow copy of the dictionary.

Comment: I see, thank you. dict.copy() is very useful thanks for the link also.